# Open and read Excel file in C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I am trying to open an Excel file located on my local computer and take out a few values from it. The values are a mix of strings and numbers located in different cells. The Excel file will be opened using `openFileDialog`. I am using C# and developing a desktop application (WPF). This is the code I am implementing:

```
     Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        string workbookPath = "C:/Users/b_prashanth/Documents/26. Workload Modeling generic template.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
        Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
        string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
        Excel.Range excelCell =
    (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you've tried or this will be closed.

Comment: Does the client that will run application have excel installed?

Comment: Yes excel is installed in the client.

Answer (score 1):

I think, OpenXML SDK should help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK

It's available via nuget - DocumentFormat.OpenXML,
and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278328.aspx) you can find all classes and algorithms, what you needed

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? What's the problem you've faced?

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result != true) return;

string workbookPath = dlg.FileName;

Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
Excel.Worksheet sheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets["Sheet1"] as Excel.Worksheet; 

if (sheet == null) return;

Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value)

var yourValue = range.Text;
```

Comment: I tried this. I get an error on the line 

               "Excel.Worksheet sheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets["Sheet1"] as Excel.Worksheet;" 

saying     "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WpfApplication2.exe"...

Also, "missing.value" is not available. Instead i am using "Type.missing".

Comment: Not sure what the problem is then because this code and your code both work on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Office interop, which requires Office to be installed on the machine, you could access the Excel sheet like a database using the ADO driver.

This has been documented here many times and would be very easy.